# How to optimize this function in R?

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I have about 977 obs in `top500Stocks` which contains name of 977 stocks.

```
head(top500Stocks,10)
    ï..Symbol
1    RELIANCE
2         TCS
3    HDFCBANK
4        INFY
5  HINDUNILVR
6        HDFC
7   ICICIBANK
8   KOTAKBANK
9        SBIN
10 BAJFINANCE
```

and I have Date, OHLC and Adj.Close, Vol and Ret of each stocks from the top500Stocks in stocksRetData

```
  head(stocksRetData[[1]],3)
          Date     Open     High      Low    Close Adj.Close    Volume   Ret
    1 20000103 28.18423 29.86935 28.18423 38.94457  29.86935  28802010 0.000
    2 20000104 30.66445 32.26056 29.82188 42.06230  32.26056  61320457 0.080
    3 20000105 30.45677 34.16522 30.45677 43.71014  33.52440 173426953 0.039
```

Now for a given lookbackPeriod  and holdPeriod I am trying to run the below function but it takes about 1 minute. How can I make it faster? Because I have to run for multiple lookbackPeriod and holdPeriod it will take forever to complete.

```
CalC.MOD_MScore.Ret.High <- function(lookbackPeriod, holdPeriod, fnoStocks, 
                                     stocksRetData, totalTestPeriod) {
  
  #We go through each stock and calculate Modified mscores where we give more importance to recent data
  
  WeeklyData <- list()
  wmean <- function(x, k) mean(seq(k)/k * x)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(fnoStocks)){
    
    out <- stocksRetData[[i]]
    out <- tail(out,totalTestPeriod)
    
    if (nrow(out)==totalTestPeriod){
      
      tempDF <- transform(out, wtMean = rollapply(Ret, lookbackPeriod, wmean, 
                                                  k = lookbackPeriod, align = "right", 
                                                  fill = NA))
      
      tempDF <- transform(tempDF, ExitVal = rollapply(lead(High, holdPeriod), 
                                                      holdPeriod, max, 
                                                      align = "right", 
                                                        fill = NA))
      
      tempDF$NWeekRet <- (tempDF$ExitVal - tempDF$Adj.Close ) / tempDF$Adj.Close
      
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$wtMean),]
      tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$ExitVal),]
      tempDF$StockName = fnoStocks[i,1]
      tempDF$WeekNum = c((lookbackPeriod):(nrow(tempDF)+lookbackPeriod-1))
      
      WeeklyData[[i]] <- data.frame(
        StockName = tempDF$StockName,
        WeekNum = tempDF$WeekNum,
        M_Score = tempDF$wtMean,
        NWeekRet = tempDF$NWeekRet,
        stringsAsFactors =  FALSE
      )
      
    }
  }# i ends here
  
  return(bind_rows(WeeklyData))
}
```

This takes more than a minute to complete.

```
 a <- CalC.MOD_MScore.Ret.High(4,14,fnoStocks = top500Stocks, stocksRetData = stocksRetData, 2000)
```

Comment: you probably need to use `datatable` and avoid for loop. You could consider using RCPP Just note that no one is going to convert the code for you.

Comment: @Onyambu sure, do you have any examples that I can refer to?

Comment: Not really in mind. Probably you should fix your question. Probably there are even better ways of doing the same task. Instead of showing the code, show the expected output and explain how to get to the expected output

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because duplicate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261477/r-code-optimization/261509#261509

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't suggest using `for`-loops in `R`. I would rewrite your loop with a `lapply` like

```
CalC.MOD_MScore.Ret.High <- function(lookbackPeriod, holdPeriod, fnoStocks, 
                                     stocksRetData, totalTestPeriod) {
  
  #We go through each stock and calculate Modified mscores where we give more importance to recent data
  
  wmean <- function(x, k) mean(seq(k)/k * x)
  
  WeeklyData <- lapply(1:nrow(fnoStocks), function(i) {
    out <- stocksRetData[[i]]
    out <- tail(out,totalTestPeriod)
    if(nrow(out)!=totalTestPeriod) return(NULL)
    
    tempDF <- transform(out, wtMean = rollapply(Ret, lookbackPeriod, wmean, 
                                                k = lookbackPeriod, align = "right", 
                                                fill = NA))
    
    tempDF <- transform(tempDF, ExitVal = rollapply(lead(High, holdPeriod), 
                                                    holdPeriod, max, 
                                                    align = "right", 
                                                    fill = NA))
    
    tempDF$NWeekRet <- (tempDF$ExitVal - tempDF$Adj.Close ) / tempDF$Adj.Close
    
    tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$wtMean),]
    tempDF <- tempDF[!is.na(tempDF$ExitVal),]
    tempDF$StockName = fnoStocks[i,1]
    tempDF$WeekNum = c((lookbackPeriod):(nrow(tempDF)+lookbackPeriod-1))
    
    data.frame(
      StockName = tempDF$StockName,
      WeekNum = tempDF$WeekNum,
      M_Score = tempDF$wtMean,
      NWeekRet = tempDF$NWeekRet,
      stringsAsFactors =  FALSE
    )
  })
  
  return(bind_rows(WeeklyData))
}
```

Having an `lapply` makes it easier to throw some parallelization-tools on it.
You can have a look at the package `parallel`. With this package, you can parallelize and make use of multiple cores on you machine. Therefore, you need to setup a cluster, which produces some overhead, but I think it will pay out in your case. To use it, setup a cluster via `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())`. The `detectCores`-method gets the number of available cores on your machine. Then, you can edit the `lapply` to

```
WeeklyData <- parallel::parLapply(cl = cl, 1:nrow(fnoStocks), function(i) {
  ...
})
```

After all your caluclations finished, call `parallel::stopCluster(cl)` to stop the cluster.

Comment: When I tried with parallel::parLapply .... I got the error :  Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  8 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'stocksRetData' not found

Comment: When setting up clusters, the clusters do not know the variables inside your current environment. Therefore you have to move your data into the cluster via `parallel::clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("your","needed","datanames","and","functions"), envir = environment())` before the `parLapply`.